# Canvas beeing black when doing events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have tried using jCanvas to make seats on my avatar system. Previously in the process i do draw an image (the background for the canvas).

The fields should be placed over the canvas, it does when i run it, but when i click the "layer" below, it turn the previously set background to BLACK?

```
g.addLayer({
method: 'drawRect',
x: left_px, y: top_px,
width: client.constants.ROOM_GRID_WIDTH, height: client.constants.ROOM_GRID_HEIGHT,
// Event bindings
mousedown: function(params) {
    alert("clicked!");
}}).drawLayers();
```

Drawing background:

```
$("canvas").drawImage({
 source: "http://xxxx.dk/framework/gfxs/rooms/"+callback[1],
 x: 0, y: 0,
 width: 760,
 height: 552,
 fromCenter: false
 });
```